# Creating form name and object name as parameters of a function

Tags: vb.net, function

I'm trying to pass form name and object as parameters of my public sub because I have 2 forms and they are almost identical to one another.

For example I have richtextbox1 in Form1 and I also have richtextbox1 in Form2, I would like to create a public sub something like this.

```
Public Sub Sub1(ByVal frm_name As form, Byval obj_name As object)
    frm_name.obj_name.Lines.Length 'Get the length of lines of that richtextbox
End Sub
```

Then when I want to call it

```
'Form 1 Codes
Public Class Form1
   Private Sub Tmr1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Tmr1.Tick
       Sub1(me, richtextbox1)
   End Sub
End Class

'Form 2 Codes
Public Class Form2
   Private Sub Tmr1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Tmr1.Tick
       Sub1(me, richtextbox1)
   End Sub
End Class
```

It is not working the way I want it, is there anything I can do for it to work?

Comment: Use TypeOf the you can use a case to cast the object to the correct control...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about it.  You are saying that you're passing the names of things but you're not.  You're not passing the name of a form; you're passing the form itself.  You're not passing the name of an object; you're passing the object itself.  What is the actual point of this?  It's to get the number of lines in a `RichTextBox`, right?  So, write a method that takes a `RichTextBox` as an argument and then call it passing a `RichTextBox`.

```
Public Sub Sub1(rtb As RichTextBox)
    Dim lineCount = rtb.Lines.Length

    '...
End Sub

'Form 1 Codes
Public Class Form1
   Private Sub Tmr1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Tmr1.Tick
       Sub1(richtextbox1)
   End Sub
End Class

'Form 2 Codes
Public Class Form2
   Private Sub Tmr1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Tmr1.Tick
       Sub1(richtextbox1)
   End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be working fine, but when I add a timer it says 'enabled is not a member of system.threading.timer' My code is something like this `Public Sub Sub1(rtb As RichTextBox, tmr As Timer)` Then on my usage `tmr.Enabled = True`

Comment: You're using the wrong type of `Timer`.  In a WinForms project, you should generally be using a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`.  In some cases, a `System.Timers.Timer` is appropriate.  It is very rare that you should be using a `System.Threading.Timer` directly.